# Is there any edge detection in opencv(python) with white background?

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

Is there any edge detection filter in OpenCV like canny but I want the background to be white and the edges in black color

Comment: Make a copy of your image, invert it, and use the common edge detection.

Comment: @HansHirse: this doesn't make sense, edge detection is contrast-independent. I guess that the OP wants contrast reversal *after* edge filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such concept but you can achieve this way

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("arch.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
ret,th2 = cv2.threshold(edges,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


cv2.imshow("img",th2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```